# How to add store multiselect to magento system configuration?

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, multiselect-attribute

I have a scenario where i need to be able to select magento stores like this from the system configuration section.

[image: Store view]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This goes in the `system.xml` under the `fields` tag.

```
<field_name_here translate="title" module="[module]">
    <label>Label goes here</label>
    <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
    <source_model>[module]/store</source_model>
    <sort_order>10</sort_order> <!-- feel free to change this value -->
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default><!-- can be 0 or 1 -->
    <show_in_website>0</show_in_website><!-- can be 0 or 1 -->
    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store><!-- can be 0 or 1 -->
</field_name_here>
```

Then create the source model.
For that you need a class inside your module.

`app/code/[codebool]/[Namespace]/[Module]/Model/Store.php` with this code:

```
<?php
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Store {
    public function toOptionArray() {
        return Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getStoreValuesForForm(false, true);
    }
}
```

Replace in the code above the values between `[]` with the appropriate values and you are done.

Comment: when I use this code it shows the options Yes and No in the screen not the stores. Weird stuff, any idea why?

Comment: maybe you have the wrong source model.

Comment: It shows the store information and I can select it but how can I actually save the value that was selected?  Would be great if I can save it in the core_config_table so I can use it later on.

Answer (score 1):

Marius' answer is correct, however, I'd like to add that you can use Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Store as your source_model.
Which would result in `<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_store</source_model>` in your system.xml field for your config variable.